# How does "Google password monitoring" work?

Tags: passwords, google

Google Apps has a [feature to monitor users' password strength](https://support.google.com/a/answer/139399?hl=en) and notify administrator about it. Google help says:

> View the length of each user's password along with a graph showing its
>   relative strength based on other criteria. The graph's indicators can
>   assess password strength upon user login. The indicators change over
>   time in relation to your password length requirements and common
>   passwords known to be vulnerable.

Does the fact that indicators change over time means that Google actually keeps plain-text version of the passwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and the documentation you quote demonstrates that.   Specifically:

> ...The graph's indicators can assess password strength upon **user login**...

If they need the user to log in in order to assess the password strength, that's because that is the only time when they have the password in a form they can examine.  That precludes them from storing it in plaintext (or encrypted using a key they know) which would allow them to examine it at any time.